# What makes an object "uncollectable" in python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, pyside6

I recently transitioned a python app from PySide2 to PySide6 and now I get a warning about "uncollectable garbage at shutdown". Initially, I thought this was something that only happened for Python 3.8, because for a minimal example the issue did not occur when using Python 3.9 instead. When I go back to my app, the issue persists for Python 3.9. Execution duration does not matter, so whether the app is just started to be closed or runs for hours it does not change the message.

```
gc:0: ResourceWarning: gc: 1 uncollectable objects at shutdown; use gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE) to list them
```

This is printed when I set `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE)`

```
gc:0: ResourceWarning: gc: 1 uncollectable objects at shutdown
      [<PySide6.QtCore.Property object at 0x000002AA879807F0>]
```

So this error message is not really helpful since I cannot print where this object is and how I can properly free it for destruction. I could not find any resolution online. **Therefore, I am wondering**:

- What makes garbage in Python so "uncollectable" that a warning like this is printed?
- What should I look out for to find the source of the problem?
- Is this warning really an issue to go crazy for or just "information"?

---

For anyone interested in the minimal example: If you execute the code below with Python 3.8.10 it will print the error. For 3.9.13 it's all good.

```py
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE)

from PySide6 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends import backend_qt5agg

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.resize(882, 700)
        self.setModal(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    mw = Dialog()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Is the matplotlib import required for the error? And the `setModal()`?

Comment: Didn't reproduce on Ubuntu with `PySide6-6.4.1` and `matplotlib-3.6.2`. Please check that you have up-to-date versions, and share more info on your environment.

Comment: I run it on windows 10. Matplotlib is required to reproduce the error because I think it comes from the matplotlib qt backend for rendering plots in a Qt widget. If I dont import matplotlib the error does not occur. I was running it with PySide6-6.4.0.1 (6.4.1 got released 6 days ago) and matplotlib-3.6.2. But also after upgrading PySide6, the error persists for Python 3.8 for the simple example and for Python 3.9 for my "complex" case.

Comment: Then it seems more like a bug (and then off topic), and you should probably file a report on their bug tracker.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. I'm still interested into the theory behind this error. Like, what needs to happen for an object to become uncollectable upon interpreter shutdown and what does it mean for the system? How long will it linger in memory? etc.

Comment: @Aranvir there could be various causes, like bad implementation of destructors or usage of `__del__`, not excluding a possible python bug. Theoretically speaking, when the python interpreter quits (meaning that its process has actually exited), it should free its resources anyway, including uncollected references.